# PHP MySQLi issue with prepared SELECT variable not binding

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Having another PHP issue that's probably something simple, but I'd really appreciate any help!

My function does a mysqli count but the $count parameter it gets bound to is not changed, even though the sql runs fine and there are no errors.

The function:

```
function itemsCount ($conn, $list_id) {
    $count = 0;
    if (!($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT count(uid) FROM collection.user_list_item WHERE list_id = ?"))) {
      echo "Prepare failed: " . $mysqli->error;
   }
   if (!($stmt->bind_param('i', $list_id))) {
      echo "Bind failed: " . $stmt->error;
   }
   if (!($stmt->execute())) {
      echo "Execute failed: " . $stmt->error;
   }
   if (!($stmt->bind_result($count))) {
      echo "Bind failed: " . $stmt->error;
   }
   echo $count;
   $stmt->close();
   return $count;
}
```

And the call:

```
public function doAdd ($conn, $list_id, $item_id) {
   if ($this->itemsCount($conn, $list_id) < 20) {
      ...do stuff ...
   }
}
```

Sorry the code isn't very nice, but please help point me in the right direction!

Comment: You still need to call `$stmt->fetch()` after `$stmt->bind_result()` to actually retrieve a row.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelBerkowski! I feel very stupid now...

Answer (score -1):

var_dump the $list_id,  the param bind i, expect a integer. I expect your var to be a string which you can see with the var_dump. Either cast the string to int, or use a different param bind.

Comment: PHP will automatically convert a string to integer whenever necessary.

Comment: The `i` parameter to `bind_param` tells it that it's necessary.